# Simple Java GUI Program

Tags: java, swing

My JPanel and JTextField are for some reason not appearing. The programs only task is to add a number to the counter every time the button is clicked. No compiling errors nor console issues. Simply not showing up??

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*; 

public class Swing  
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            final JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame ("Counter (Program 1/2)"); 
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            mainFrame.setSize(400, 200);
            mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
            mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 


            JButton countButton = new JButton("Count up");
            mainFrame.add(countButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            countButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    JTextField clicks = new JTextField(BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
                    mainFrame.add(firstPanel);
                    mainFrame.add(clicks, BorderLayout.NORTH);      
                    int counter = 1;
                    counter++;
                    String textField = String.valueOf(counter);
                    clicks.setText(textField);

                }
            });     
        }
    });     
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Don't add the JTextField and JPanel *inside* the ActionListener. This makes no sense since you'll be re-adding new components each time the button is pressed. Instead add them on GUI creation, before calling `setVisible(true)` on the GUI. Then update the text field's text in the ActionListener.

As a side recommendation: try to make your class more object oriented by giving it fields, a constructor, and getting most all of that code out of the static main method.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistakes:

1. Add `clicks` and `firstpanel` to the frame in `run` method, not in the `actionPerformed`
2. BorderLayout.CENTER should be pass as a parameter to `add` method, not to the text field constructor.
3. Define count as `static`. This is not the best way but in your situation it is the easiest way.
4. Call `mainFrame.setVisible(true);` after you added all your components.

Here is the working code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Swing {

    public static int counter = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                final JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Counter (Program 1/2)");

                mainFrame.setSize(400, 200);
                mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JButton countButton = new JButton("Count up");
                mainFrame.add(countButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

                final JTextField clicks = new JTextField(String.valueOf(counter));
                JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
                mainFrame.add(firstPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                mainFrame.add(clicks, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                countButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        counter++;
                        String textField = String.valueOf(counter);
                        clicks.setText(textField);

                    }
                });

                mainFrame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there any way to align the counter in the center of the JTextField?

Comment: `clicks.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);` this will do the job.